# Insert data from another table on specific rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I successfully inserted data from other table, but data was inserted on other rows. how to specify condition that will let data inserted on the particular row, most of query has conditions from other (old)table.

```
INSERT INTO machine_types( machine_id)
    SELECT DISTINCT machine_id 
    FROM machine_events
    WHERE platform_id = '70ZOvy' AND cpu = 0.25 AND memory = 0.2498
```

`machine_types` table has `machine_type` column, I want the data inserted on `machine_type = 1`.

**machine_types** table:

```
machine_id    // has null value now
cpu
memory
platform
machine_type
```

**machine_events**:

```
machine_id
cpu
memory
platform
```

Question is how I am going to write the SQL query to insert the data into records that have `machine_type = 1`?

Note. `machine_types` table has only 10 records, and the new records that is going to be inserted is 126 records. All of these records is going to `machine_type = 1`.

**Machine_types** table:

```
machine_type    platform    cpu     memory    machine_id
1                 HofLG     0.25    0.2498      NULL
2                 HofLG     0.5     0.03085     NULL
3                 HofLG     0.5     0.06158     NULL
4                 HofLG     0.5     0.1241      NULL
```

**Machine_events** table:

```
time machine_id     platform_id  cpu    memory  machine_type
0      5             HofLG       0.25   0.2493     1
0      6             HofLG       0.5    0.03085    1
0      7             HofLG       0.5    0.2493     2
0      10            HofLG       0.5    0.2493     2
```

Null on first table should changed to get machine_id from second table based on machine_type.

**machine_types** after `machine_id` just updated:

```
    machine_type    platform    cpu     memory    machine_id
    1                 HofLG    0.25     0.2498      5
    1                 HofLG    0.5      0.03085     6
    2                 HofLG    0.5      0.03085     NULL
    3                 HofLG    0.5      0.06158     NULL
    4                 HofLG     0.5     0.1241      NULL
```

Comment: try adding this at the end of the query  ` and machine_type=1`

Comment: I tried it before didn't work, it just added the new data on the end of table

Comment: i am assuming they all in one table

Comment: You should provide the table structure of both these tables you are working with. it'll help us to answer

Comment: Are you trying to update the current records rather than insert new records? If so, you need an update statement and not an insert statement.

Comment: I update the Q, the machine_id in machine_types table has null value now.

Comment: I think it would be nice to give us a visual representation of what you are expecting the table to have. A few rows from the `machine_events` table and the expected outcome in `machine_types`. Before and after.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it's clear I didn't understand your question. I suggest you edit your question to make it really obvious what you're trying to do: give an example of what your tables look like before and after your desired change.

Comment: Q is updated, thanks guys for your comments

Comment: i see that the second table has two rows with machine_type=1, one with machine_id=5 and another with machine_id=6. Please explain from where do you want to get other fields (platform, cpu, memory) of first table? the values of these fields are repeated for row 2,3 in final result! Are you sure about this?

Comment: Consider whats wrong with this scenario: `DELETE FROM Table1 where machine_type = 1`, then `INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT ... FROM Table2 where machine_type = 1`. here we use values of second table for [platform, cpu, memory] columns. if this is not what you need, please explain exactly from where should they come from?

Comment: dear saeed, plz check the tables again, I correct some

Comment: @jou but it is not clear yet: we have 2 rows with machine_type = 1 in final results. the first one has original values of [platform, cpu, memory]. but how do you get the values of these fields for second row? i can't find corresponding row with `HofLGz, 0.5, 0.03085` for machine_id=6

Comment: There is no HofLGz I updated it.

Comment: SOLVED, on other way